# What's your preferred de-esser plugin?

Tags: plug-ins, de-esser, mix, software, recommendations

I used the waves one and now i'm trying the Eiosis E2deesser: I found its approach really interesting and natural sounding. I use a combination of that plugin and multiband compression.

I have read about the sonnox, but have only used it for a few hours.

What do you use?

Davide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Oxford Suppressor.

I also use a Dynamic EQ.

Comment: I totaly agree that manual de-essing is much better than automatic, but it's only possible when you have plenty of time, and short programm to edit. when you have to mix (like here in italy) a 90 min tv episode in just a few days, you have to find the compromise between quality and intelligibility (and avoid to work overtime and over (tight) budget). :)
hope to here more about your strip-silence/detective experiment!

Comment: there is, of course, always the alternate track method. if you're worried about the whole dialogue track getting mucked up, duplicate it and put your de-esser on the new track. then mix between the two as needed, even if it's just a frame or two. with the proper settings you can get a smooth transition without too much tonal shift, and it's a reasonable compromise between time management and getting some detailed reduction.

Comment: @Ryan - Switch between the two with crossfades as needed. You leave the duplicate completely out of the mix until you need it. I learned this trick from an engineer who had to do this kind of stuff before you could program automation. It's pretty much the same thing, but I feel like it gives me just a little bit more flexibility when I need it. It's also a lot faster, because the track is already there, no switching between track views. So, it can make for a faster mix session in the right scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Only ever used the Waves one and the one built into Logic.  Don't really use a de-esser that often, but I've always liked the one built into Logic better.

If I'm doing music, I often manually de-ess in PT.

What are you using it for?  Dialogue or singing?

Comment: I use it for dialogue (production and adr).
I'm really not a fan of de-essing, but in tight timing and with trouble sounding lines it's really a time saver.

Answer (score 2):

I actually just started using iZotope Alloy and find its de-esser to be quite good and versatile (for more than just Ss).

--jpf

Comment: cool. I never used it. i'll give it a try. how does the EQ (and the other module sound? and how heavy is on the cpu?  

Comment: It's a terrific suite of tools with *very* low CPU. Best to d/l their demo at iZotope and give it a real workout for your projects!

Answer (score 1):

Wave Renaissance De-esser is my favourite.

Mike.

Answer (score 1):

I either manually gain down the "esses" or use a multiband compressor with the band on the offending frequency set to high ratio, fast attack, fast release.

Answer (score 0):

I enjoy nuendo's de-esser, it works for me, however it is a plugin on 3 but not on nuendo 4, do i have to download it, if so from where?

Answer (score 0):

My personal favourite is the Massey Desser... great sounding and very flexible.

Comment: Agreed, this is my fav as well. Also can "Re-Ess" if you actually want more sibilance - like in pulling just hi-hat hits out of a mic that has too much bleed from the other drums on it. 

Answer (score 0):

Volume graph
The dialogue editor usually does some while editing & does others during final mix, as they become apparent....

Answer (score 0):

I use the volume graph and I have the digidesign deesser on the dialogue bus, which is mostly bypassed, but automated and active if there are too many S's. I always use it in HF only mode.

I only use it at the very end of working with dialogue, and only if necessary.